# Old question deserted

Tags: discussion, support

I like to follow the questions where I post an answer .... and right now I see a lots of post with good answers that has been left behind by the user who asked the question.

In order to improve the site and clean a bit how can this be handled?

It's correct to flag some post for these reason?

To make it more clear I just wonder about the **Time** of the questions, I just ask about if there is some policy for that and if the moderators pay attention or not on that details.

*Note that some questions itself expose particular problems and I don't think can be useful for another user*

As an example [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19411804/2887133)

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is. Are you worried about the fact that the user didn't accept an answer?

Comment: @eddie_cat *In order to improve the site and clean a bit*

Comment: Improve how? Clean how?

Comment: What do you see that's wrong and needs to be "cleaned"?

Comment: Just so many questions when you search .... questions over a year and voted down I just question if there is some policy to flag that or not or just stay in the site ...

Comment: It's only got one downvote and seems to be on-topic and not of terrible quality. There's plenty of much worse crap around to clean if you're interested in doing that ;)

Comment: Don't flag. What would you expect to be done anyway? What should the response be to your flag?

Comment: @eddie_cat thanks that question was just an example .. But thanks

Comment: @Bart I don't know if there is some policy to erase useless questions by the moderators but just chill was a simple question

Comment: If you don't think a question is useful you can downvote it, that's really the only appropriate action here

Comment: Might have been a simple question, but it lacked any detail. That's what we were trying to find out.

Comment: @eddie_cat Thanks that can be the asnwer just simple . . . I think that meta was able to hold this kind of questions ...  but seems not

Comment: It's a valid question for meta, but you weren't very clear initially in what you were asking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless the question is low quality or off topic in some way there's probably little point in doing anything.

While the question may well have been abandoned by the original asker, the fact that it has an answer could still be useful to some future visitor. It does no harm to leave these questions on the site - they are simply part of the ["long tail"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).